# Proof for the derivative of a power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, proof-explanation

**Theorem:** Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions analytic on the domain $\Omega$ converge uniformly on each closed subdisc of $\Omega$ to the analytic function $f$. Then the sequence $\{f_n'\}$ of derivatives converges uniformly on each closed subdisc of $\Omega$ to the derivative $f'$

**Proof:** Let $\overline D$ be any closed subdisc od $\Omega$. We must show that for any $\varepsilon\gt0$, there is an index $n_\varepsilon$ such that if $n\gt n_\varepsilon$, then $\left|f'(\zeta)-f'_n(\zeta)\right|\lt\varepsilon$ for all $\zeta\in\Omega$

We use the Integral Formula, $$f'(\zeta)-f'_n(\zeta)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma\frac{f(z)-f_n(z)}{(z-\zeta)^2}\;dz$$ which inmediatly yields $$\left|f'(\zeta)-f'_n(\zeta)\right|\le\frac{1}{2\pi}\max_{z\in\Gamma}\frac{|f(z)-f_n(z)|}{|z-\zeta|^2}\cdot length\left(\Gamma\right)$$ Here, $\Gamma$ is a circle in $\Omega$, which has the same center as $\overline D$ but a slightly larger radius. In fact, let $d\gt0$ be the shortest distance from $\Gamma$ to $\overline D$; that is $$d=radius\left(\Gamma\right)-radius\left(\Omega\right)$$

Now let $\varepsilon^*=\varepsilon 2\pi\;d^2/length\left(\Gamma\right)$. Since $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on the closed subdisc bounded by $\Gamma$ to its limit $f$, we know there is an index $n^*$ such that $n\gt n^*$ implies $|f(z)-f_n(z)|\lt \varepsilon^*$ for all $z$ on $\Gamma$. Thus the standard estimate above assures us that if $n\gt n^*$, then $$\left|f'(\zeta)-f'_n(\zeta)\right|\lt {1\over 2\pi}{\varepsilon^*\over d^2}\cdot length(\Gamma)=\varepsilon$$ for every $\zeta$ in $\overline D$. Thus if we define $n_\varepsilon=n^*$, we have satisfied the requirement for uniform convergence. Done

Sorry for posting the full proof for such a short question but it is only the last step that I can't understand. Why define $\varepsilon^*=\varepsilon 2\pi\;d^2/length\left(\Gamma\right)$? Is it because $|z-\zeta|^2\ge d^2$ for every $z\in\Gamma$ (only equal when $z$ is on the rim of $\overline D$)? That would ensure that $$\max_{z\in\Gamma}\frac{|f(z)-f_n(z)|}{|z-\zeta|^2}\lt {\varepsilon^*\over d^2}$$ but then why is it necessary to define $\varepsilon^*$ if $|f(z)-f_n(z)|$ can be as small as we want?

Comment: merely a matter of convention.